# Show textview depending on time in VideoView?

Tags: android, textview, android-videoview

I want to show text one after the other on certain interval of time depending on the time of videoview. Let me provide a brief note on this: Say the video that i play is of 20sec. So here I wise to display textview(with different text) on interval of 5sec, 8sec, 15sec. and at 20th sec. the whole textview will disappear.
 So any hints or anything that may help me to fix this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no convenient listener that reports back the progress. You can possibly use a `Handler` that queues up delayed `Message`s based on the times you want the `TextView` to show (so use `Handler.sendMessageDelayed`) and as they fire do the right thing to the TextView. If the video gets paused or is delayed (perhaps from playing over the network) you will need to take additional steps to verify that the video's position is right, but that should work.